# AWS SQS Queue declining message count

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

The host that my SQS app runs on recently experienced some external DNS resolution issues. This meant that suddenly, I couldn't hit the SQS API endpoints. As a part of figuring out what was going on, I logged into the AWS console only to find the messages count slowly declining.

If the messages could not have been consumed by my app, how could the number of messages in the queue be declining?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SQS automatically deletes messages that have been in a queue for more than the `maximum message retention period`.

By default, the message retention period is 4 days. However, you can set the message retention period to any value from 60 seconds to 1,209,600 seconds (14 days) in the AWS console.

[Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-architecture.html)